# getsupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

My app crashes each time with error as `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sidssol.com.bit_taxi_b2c/sidssol.com.bit_taxi_b2c.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException` for getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true),pasted all the required code.Can anyone check this code

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {
       adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        navDrawerItems);


                mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

                // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

                mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                        R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                        R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                        R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                )
}
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Theme.Test.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Test.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Androidmainfest.xml

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".loginForm"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see your theme states there is no actionbar

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

if you are using that theme you will need to use the `Toolbar` or change your theme to use the actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```html
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

with follow

```html
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

or change `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` with  `android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"`

Comment: Still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also, ActionBarActivity is deprecated, you should use AppCompatActivity.